# websocket server on python.problems

Tags: python, websocket

I faced the task to implement a simple server handles for Python with support for websocket. Of course I know about tornadoIO, but the problem is in implementing it handles.
Step of connections and Handshake (exchange of private keys), I did, but then i have problems.
1) The message from the client (browser) does come, but they coded. I found information about it, but could not figure out how to decode them. Documentation says that the message is hidden under the mask (as I understand it a XOR), but the key to opening this mask nos dended by client (browser), or i not see it.
2) messages, which sends the server, the client (browser) are ignored. Sending according to the documentation

```
conn.send(bytes(0x00))
conn.send(u'test'.encode('utf-8'))
conn.send(bytes(0xFF))
```

uploaded source code [here](http://zalil.ru/32842776)
and i post source here

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import socket,sys,hashlib,time
from base64 import b64encode
from threading import Thread
#===================================
bindto=['127.3.1.4',80]
thr_kill=False

def getsett(text,ss,si,es):
#this function i'm use for cut strings by known patterns
   global getsett_i1,getsett_i2
   if text==None: return None
   if ss==None: return None
   if es==None: return None
   text1=text.lower()
   ss=ss.lower()
   es=es.lower()
   if ss!='': getsett_i1=text1.find(ss,si)
   else: getsett_i1=si
   if getsett_i1==-1: return None
   if es!='': getsett_i2=text1.find(es,getsett_i1+len(ss))
   else: getsett_i2=len(text1)
   if getsett_i2==-1: return None
   return text[getsett_i1+len(ss):getsett_i2]

def thr_waitclient():
   global bindto,thr_kill
   serv=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   serv.bind((bindto[0],bindto[1]))
   while thr_kill==False:
      serv.listen(1)
      conn,adr=serv.accept()
      data=conn.recv(4096)
      print data
#checking connection type
      if getsett(data,'connection: ',0,"\r\n").lower()=='upgrade' and getsett(data,'upgrade: ',0,"\r\n").lower()=='websocket':
#handshake
         wbs=getsett(data,'Sec-WebSocket-Key: ',0,"\r\n")
         conn.send("HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\nUpgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: "+b64encode(hashlib.sha1(wbs+'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11').digest())+"\r\nSec-WebSocket-Origin: *\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\nOrigin: *\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials:true\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type\r\n\r\n")
#wait for clien's messahe,then send response
         while True:
            print conn.recv(4096) #first problem:message is coded
            conn.send(bytes(0x00))
            conn.send(u'test'.encode('utf-8'))
            conn.send(bytes(0xFF))
            #second problem: client ignore message
            time.sleep(0.5)
      else:
         conn.close()
   serv.close()

Thread(None,thr_waitclient).start()
while thr_kill!=True:
   time.sleep(0.3)
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Have you looked at existing implementations such as autobahn, ws4py, txws?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different major variations of the WebSocket protocol. Your example code is a mixure of both that won't work for either protocol.

Recent versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE10 use the newer HyBi/IETF protocol. Older versions of Chrome and current versions of Safari (desktop and mobile) use the older Hixie protocol.

The Hixie protocol used '\x00' to indicate the beginning of a frame and '\xff' to indicate the end of a frame. The Hixie protocol did not mask browser to server data. There are two major versions of the Hixie protocol: 75 and 76. Version 76 has an additional piece of data that is exchanged right after the headers but before the normal frames.

The newer HyBi/IETF protocol uses a 2-10 byte header that contains the payload length and no separate ending marker. In the newer protocol, payload data from browser to server is masked using a 4 byte running XOR mask. The first 4 bytes after the header are the mask in the browser to server case. Server to browser data is no masked. The handshake headers and process are also different for the HyBi protocol.

Many WebSocket servers support both Hixie and HyBi/IETF versions of the WebSocket protocol (you can determine from the headers sent by the browser what version it is using).

Here are the specs for the various protocol versions:

- [Hixie 75](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76)
- [Hixie 76](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76)
- [HyBi/IETF 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)

Comment: i'm really mistaked with versions of protocol. i'm use right handshake and wrong sending and receiving))can anyone help me with this?i'm say about algorithm for unmasking and algorithm for correct sending daa to client. i'm afraid i haven't enough knowledge for this :(

Comment: Thx again **kanaka**, i'm reread documentation and now all work fine!